# Showing File Copy Status on a Progress Bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I am trying to perform a low-level file copy but also display my progress using a determinate progress bar. Is there any way I can do this? I have looked on many mail archives, and one blog post explaining on how to do it in carbon which didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nice article about this on the Cocoa Is My Girlfriend blog titled "[Cocoa Tutorial: File Copy With Progress Indicator](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/05/03/cocoa-tutorial-file-copy-with-progress-indicator/)". It's pretty straightforward, as the article says, but not obvious or well-documented.

Comment: Alex Zielenski: If that article was the blog post you mentioned in your question, you may want to ask another question with the specific problem you had.

Comment: The problem was that the callback was never getting called even though I had the ScheduleRunLoop method or whatever it is.

Answer (score 1):

Check this project out, I created it to help people that are struggling with this issue as I once did. Is not perfect but is a start, you can build on top of it.

https://github.com/larod/FileCopyDemo

[image]